# Convergence of Fourier series - strange graph in proof

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, spectral-theory

I am reading a text that states the following related to convergence of Fourier series:

> $$g_K(x) =
> > \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{x-2\pi}^x\frac{\sin\left[\left(K+\frac{1}{2}\right)t\right]}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}t\right)}f(x-t)\,dt$$
>
> The kernel $\sin(K+\frac{1}{2})t/\sin(\frac{1}{2}t)$ of the previous
>   integral is plotted for several values of $K$ in the following figure.

However, the caption of the corresponding figure says "a plot of $\sin[(K+\frac{1}{2})t]/[(K+\frac{1}{2})t]$", and indeed, the plots are of

$$\frac{\sin[(K+\frac{1}{2})t]}{(K+\frac{1}{2})t}$$

for several $K$.  Is the author then plotting a completely wrong function, or could I be missing something?  It seems too wrong to simply be a typo.  Thanks all.

Comment: Which book is that?

Comment: See formula 3.12 on page 22 (and the figure on the following page) of Numerical Analysis of Spectral Methods, by Gottlieb and Orszag (see http://books.google.com/books?id=ycITkwWMRVkC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false )

Comment: Ok, yes, indeed the figure and the formula are not exactly what you need to prove the convergence of Fourier series. I would put up a guess that someone copied the numerator for quicker typing and erased $\sin$ instead of $K+$.

Comment: Perhaps, but the caption of the figure corresponds to the graph of the figure.  This strikes me as most strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the combination of this text

[image: snapshot1]

and this figure

[image: snapshot2]

is clearly a mistake. It's not uncommon for a student to be charged with making plots for a book, and Artem gave a plausible guess for how a mistake like this could happen.